# JavaScript change for-loop condition while looping (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a code that looks kinda like this.

And what i want to achive is to change the for loop codition if the div that is checked has child divs.

```
var condition = divs.querySelectorAll('div');
for(i = 0; i < condition.length; i++){
    if(condition[i].querySelectorAll('div').length > 0){
         condition = condition[i].querySelectorAll('div');
         i = 0;
    }else{
         // Last div reached.
         break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone out there know how to achive this effect.
Do i have to use an other type of loop?

EDIT:

Since it seems i was wrong about what code was wrong, i now post my messy piece of code:

```
var posX = e.clientX;
var posY = e.clientY;
function mouseDown(e){
    var getChildDivs = this.querySelectorAll('div');

    if(getChildDivs.length > 0){
        var offsetDivLeft = 0;
        var offsetDivTop = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < getChildDivs.length; i++){
            if(posX >= getChildDivs[i].offsetLeft && posX <= getChildDivs[i].offsetLeft + Math.floor(getChildDivs[i].style.width.slice(0, -2)) &&
                posY >= getChildDivs[i].offsetTop && posY <= getChildDivs[i].offsetTop + Math.floor(getChildDivs[i].style.height.slice(0, -2))){
                if(getChildDivs[i].querySelectorAll('div').length > 0){
                    offsetDivLeft = offsetDivLeft + getChildDivs[i].offsetLeft;
                    offsetDivTop = offsetDivTop + getChildDivs[i].offsetTop;
                    getChildDivs = getChildDivs[i].querySelectorAll('div');
                    curDiv = getChildDivs[i];
                    i = 0;
                }else{
                    curDiv = getChildDivs[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the current result? Your code you should be just fine, `condition.length` will have the childs div length, only `i` should be -1, because it will increment when the loop is complete, starting back at 0.

Comment: upvote for specifically saying no jquery. Kudos

Comment: So you want to recursively loop through all children? Do you also want to loop through children of children?

Comment: What's this supposed to achieve? What's your actual end goal?

Comment: basicly this for loop is in a mousedown event.
So when i press down on a div, i need to check if i clicked that div or a div within that div. or even a div within that div at that exact location.
So when it reached the last div i can then grab that id of that div, if that makes sense

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Does `event.target` not give you the sought after element?

Comment: Seems very XY to me, yeah. You shouldn't have to do something like this to identify which element the mousedown was triggered on.

Comment: @prosch: This should give you the idea -- https://jsfiddle.net/fsgnbysc/

Comment: I now added my peice of code, maybe this can help understand better, let me know if there is something unclear in my code.
the mousedown even is triggered by the a set div that will always be there

Comment: Consult the `target` property of the event. It will give you the actual div which was clicked--normally the frontmost one, which is also normally the most deeply nested one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is

```
function mouseDown(e){
  curdiv = e.target;
}
```

The `target` property of the event gives you the actual div which was clicked--normally the frontmost one, which is also normally the most deeply nested one. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

> A reference to the object that dispatched the event.

Comment: Yes that was the sulotion, for some reason i wanted it to make it harder for myself, marked this a accepted answer since its what i wanted to achive.

Answer (score 0):

i created a fiddle which loops over every child element and children of children as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/czzeaz3x/

```
var condition = divs.querySelectorAll('div');
for(i = 0; i < condition.length; i++){
if(condition[i].children.length > 0){
     condition = condition[i].querySelectorAll('div');
    alert(condition);
     i = 0;
}else{
     // Last div reached.
     break;
}
}
```

i hope it helps ;)